# Can I block with my Llanowar elves and then tap it for mana immediately afterward?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My opponent attacks with a 3/3. I block with my 1/1 [Llanowar Elves](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Llanowar%20Elves), and have all of my land tapped from my last turn. Can I now tap my Llanowar Elves after it has been declared as a blocker to play [Giant Growth](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=205224) on it, make it 4/4 until end of turn, and destroy my opponent's attacking creature when damage is dealt?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, this works just fine. Once a creature is declared as a blocker, it remains a blocker until it is specifically removed from combat (e.g. [Regeneration](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Regeneration)) or the battlefield (e.g. [Cloudshift](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cloudshift)).

One thing to note: once a creature is blocked, it remains blocked even if the blocker is removed before damage is dealt. This works great against lifelinkers, since they deal no damage to a creature that is no longer there. It works less well on tramplers, since they just deal all their damage to the player instead.

Comment: I am not 100% sure on the latest rules of magic but, do tapped blockers deal damage?  I know there was a point in the game when they did not.  The question specifically asks this

Comment: Tapping a creature that is blocking does not remove it from combat or prevent any damage. This was settled in the 6th Edition revision, around 1999 I believe.

Comment: In previous editions the Llanowar Elf in this situation would have not dealt damage (but would have survived). Would have become effectively a 0/4 creature.