# Using tap abilities after blockers have been declared

Tags: magic-the-gathering, magic-duels

Alright say i have a 3/3 gutter skulk and a paragon of open grave with a tap ability of 3 (t), another target black creature you control gains deathtouch until end of turn. I declare an attack with the gutter skulk and my opponent declares a blocker say a 4/4, can i use the tap ability to give the skulk deathtouch after the blocker is declared to kill it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this works for the same reason that you can [tap a llanowar elves for mana after blocking](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7593/can-i-block-with-my-llanowar-elves-and-then-tap-it-for-mana-immediately-afterwar). It doesn't matter which creature is activating the tap ability - be it the blocking creature itself, or any other creature - you can still activate the ability after blocks, but before damage.